# g2p-seq2seq error: 'module' object has no attribute 'core_rnn_cell'

Tags: tensorflow, cmusphinx

I'm trying to get g2p-seq2seq to work as per github instructions: https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq

However I get the following error when I try to validate the installation with `$ g2p-seq2seq --interactive --model g2p-seq2seq-cmudict`

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/g2p-seq2seq", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('g2p-seq2seq==5.0.0a0', 'console_scripts', 'g2p-seq2seq')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/g2p_seq2seq/app.py", line 82, in main
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/g2p_seq2seq/g2p.py", line 96, in load_decode_model
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/g2p_seq2seq/seq2seq_model.py", line 121, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core_rnn_cell'
```

When I checked the seq2seq_model.py script on line 121, I can see the following line:

```py
single_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.GRUCell(size)
```

tf.contrib.rnn does not seem to have this function core_rnn_cell. How do I get this to work? I'm running with Python 2.7, Tensorflow 1.4

Comment: Discussion at https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq/issues/83

Answer (score 1):

I had to downgrade the tensorflow version to 1.0 to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Tensorflow 1.3 version.

when I switched:

```
  'single_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.GRUCell(size)'
```

to

```
= 'tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(size)'
```

It worked.